# Is it possible to view custom ETW events, raised in C# with EventSource, in PerfMon? in real-time?

Tags: etw, perfmon

I want to raise ETW events from inside a server application to monitor performance.I would like to consume these events in perfMon or a similar tool so as to view the events graphically. Is this possible? (perfView is not available in my work environment, and anyway does not display events graphically)

I can raise events simply enough, I've been using the sample in Ben Watsons "Writing HighPerformance .Net Code" book, but have been unable to view these events in perfMon.exe, when adding a new data collector set .

I added code to the sample create an event-source

```
if(!EventLog.SourceExists("EtlDemo"))
{
    EventLog.CreateEventSource("EtlDemo", "EtlDemoLog");
}
```

I suspect something more needs to done for the EtlDemo "event trace provider" to be visible to perfMon (and probably Windows Performance Analyzer), but documentation seems sparse. Any ideas?

Comment: [Windows Performance Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/p/windows-performance-analyzer/9n0w1b2bxgnz) shows Generic Events in a Graph

Comment: [register the Manifest to see the EventSource in Perfmon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18238617/1466046)

Comment: Perfmon is a UI for Performance Counters not for ETW events. WPA is a viewer for ETW events. See http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2015/09/26/167117.aspx the section about Garbage collection where .NET GC events are graphed.